# Why a dangerous method doesn't work with a character element of String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, character, upcase

When I apply the `upcase!` method I get:

```
a="hello"
a.upcase!
a # Shows "HELLO"
```

But in this other case:

```
b="hello"
b[0].upcase!
b[0]  # Shows h
b # Shows hello
```

I don't understand why the `upcase!` applied to `b[0]` doesn't have any efect.

Comment: Because `b[0]` creates a new string, just like other string methods such as `upcase` without !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are selecting an individual character in a string, you're not referencing the specific character, you're calling a accessor/mutator function which performs the evaluation:

```
2.0.0-p643 :001 > hello = "ruby"
 => "ruby" 
2.0.0-p643 :002 > hello[0] = "R"
 => "R" 
2.0.0-p643 :003 > hello
 => "Ruby"
```

In the case when you run a dangerous method, the value is requested by the accessor, then it's manipulated and the new variable is updated, but because there is no longer a connection between the character and the string, it will not update the reference.

```
2.0.0-p643 :004 > hello = "ruby"
 => "ruby" 
2.0.0-p643 :005 > hello[0].upcase!
 => "R" 
2.0.0-p643 :006 > hello
 => "ruby"
```

Answer (score 3):

`b[0]` returns a new `String` every time. Check out the object id:

```
b = 'hello'
# => "hello"
b[0].object_id
# => 1640520
b[0].object_id
# => 25290780
b[0].object_id
# => 24940620
```